# how to get decimals only if number is not round in mysql

Tags: mysql, formatting

I'm trying to get a number formated as having 2 decimals if the number is not an integer and not having any if the number is an integer. Currently I'm using the following query

```
SELECT round(SUM(number),2) as Numb FROM table
```

And I get numbers like 1.00 which I'd like it to be 1

Comment: I saw a question like this yesterday and it strikes me that these questions are ill-conceived - they're asking how to do something that in most cases you shouldn't do. If a number is stored as a numeric type with a fractional component, then it's stored that way probably because there's an implicit limitation on the accuracy of the measurement. Showing the appropriate decimal places preserves that signal as to the accuracy of the value. On top of that, if you compare the output of this procedure for queries that yielded an integer and queries that didn't, it'll look ugly and inconsistent.

Comment: @Hammerite I beg to differ. I am looking into this now, and my use case is the 'amount' column in a purchasing system. I want for example to be able to purchase 5 items, or 2.4 meters of something. When purchasing items, the decimals are completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a case with modulus. Something like:

```
select 
case (number mod 1 > 0)
  when true then round(number, 2)
  else round(number, 0)
end
from Numb
```

Results:

```
select  
case (number mod 1 > 0)  
  when true then round(number, 2)   
  else round(number,0) 
end as num 
from Numb;

+------+
| num  |
+------+
|    2 |
| 1.01 |
|    5 |
| 3.01 |
| 4.25 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: how so? The query above selects all rows from Numb. I did a little test and multi row results

Comment: This is the query I'm using 'SELECT case (SUM(WorkedHours) mod 1 > 0) when true then round(SUM(WorkedHours),2) else round(SUM(WorkedHours),0)end AS TotalWorkedHours FROM timetrack.work_items w INNER JOIN timetrack.time_logs t on w.ID = t.IDWorkItem group by IDSottocommessa' and I get [TotalWorkedHours,46.19,10.00,30.00,25.00,12.00]